# How to "programmatically" ask for offer with a contact form in Magento 1.7.0.2

Tags: php, jquery, forms, magento, email

I'm looking to create a new contact form for asking an offer on a Magento Eshop.

This "**Ask for an Offer**" form will provide the option to a visitor to fill some fields  and just sent an email exactly like the default **contact form** does.

The only difference with the default contact form is that the visitor doesn't have to be loged in to send an email.

So my approach so far is to Dublicate the file **contacts/form.phtml** to **contacts/askforanoffer.phtml**

and ofcourse I created the new **xml** in folder **layout/askforanoffer.xml**

*The question is this.*
 **Where should I change to code in order that the user not to has to be loged in in order to send an email with this ask for an offer form ?**

Comment: you mean you dont want to give access to guest user ?

Comment: The guest should be able to sent a mail (ask for offer) without registering!

Comment: your problem is that guest user is not able to send email right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create separate module for this. I have also create and sharing code here. Form submitting is by ajax. May be I have missed something to remove or renaming. try to correct it.

app\etc\modules\namespace_modulename.xml

```
<Namespace_Modulename>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
    </Namespace_Modulename>
```

app\code\local\Namespace\Modulename\Helper\Data.php

```
<?php class Namespace_Modulename_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{

}
?>
```

app\code\local\Namespace\Modulename\etc\config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Namespace_Modulename>
            <version>0.0.01</version>
        </Namespace_Modulename>
    </modules>
    <frontend>

        <routers>
            <contacts>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Namespace_Modulename before="Mage_Contacts">Namespace_Modulename</Namespace_Modulename>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </contacts>
        </routers>

    </frontend>

    <global>
        <helpers>
            <Modulename>
                <class>Namespace_Modulename_Helper</class>
            </Modulename>
        </helpers>
        <template>
            <email>
                <havequestion_email_email_template translate="label" module="contacts">
                    <label>Have a Question Form</label>
                    <file>havequestion_form.html</file>
                    <type>text</type>
                </havequestion_email_email_template>
            </email>
        </template>
    </global>

</config>
```

app\code\local\Namespace\Modulename\controller\IndexController.php

```
 public function havequestionpostAction()
    {
        $template_path = 'havequestion_email_email_template';
        //$post = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
        $post = array (
                'name' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('name'), 
                'email' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('email'),
                'comment' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('comment')

                );

        if ( $post ) {
            $translate = Mage::getSingleton('core/translate');
            /* @var $translate Mage_Core_Model_Translate */
            $translate->setTranslateInline(false);
            try {
                $postObject = new Varien_Object();
                $postObject->setData($post);

                $error = false;

                if (!Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['name']) , 'NotEmpty')) {
                    $error = true;                  
                }

                if (!Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['comment']) , 'NotEmpty')) {
                    $error = true;                  
                }

                if (!Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['email']), 'EmailAddress')) {
                    $error = true;                  
                }

                if (Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['hideit']), 'NotEmpty')) {
                    $error = true;                  
                }

                if ($error) {
                    throw new Exception();
                }

                $mailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');

                /* @var $mailTemplate Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template */


                $senderDetail = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_'.Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_SENDER));
                $senderDetail['name'] = $post['name'];

                $mailTemplate->setDesignConfig(array('area' => 'frontend'))
                    ->setReplyTo($post['email'])
                    ->sendTransactional(
                        $template_path,
                        $senderDetail,
                        //Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_SENDER),
                        Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT),
                        null,
                        array('data' => $postObject)
                    );

                if (!$mailTemplate->getSentSuccess()) {
                    throw new Exception();
                }

                $translate->setTranslateInline(true);

                //Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Your inquiry was submitted and will be responded to as soon as possible. Thank you for contacting us.'));
                //$this->_redirectUrl($post['currentpage']);
                echo 'SUCCESS';

                return;
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                $translate->setTranslateInline(true);

                //Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addError(Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Unable to submit your request. Please, try again later'));
                //$this->_redirectUrl($post['currentpage']);
                echo '<div class="error-msg">Unable to submit your request. Please, try again later.</div>';                
                return;
            }

        } else {
            echo '<div class="error-msg">Unable to submit your request. Please, try again later.</div>';
            //$this->_redirectUrl($post['currentpage']);
            return;
        }
    }

}
```

app\design\frontend\default\YOUR_TEMPLATE_PATH\template\contacts\havequestionform.phtml

```
<div class="form-add">
<form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>contacts/index/havequestionpost/" id="havequestionForm" method="post">
        <div class="question-ajax-msg"></div>
        <ul class="form-list">
            <li class="fields">
                <div class="field">
                    <label for="name" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Name') ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input name="name" id="name" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Name') ?>" value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->helper('contacts')->getUserName()) ?>" class="input-text required-entry" type="text" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="field">
                    <label for="email" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Email') ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input name="email" id="email" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Email') ?>" value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->helper('contacts')->getUserEmail()) ?>" class="input-text required-entry validate-email" type="text" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>           
            <li class="wide">
                <label for="comment" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Comment') ?></label>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <textarea name="comment" id="comment" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Comment') ?>" class="required-entry input-text" cols="5" rows="3"></textarea>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>

    <div class="">
        <p class="required" style="text-align:left"><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('* Required Fields') ?></p>
                    <button type="submit" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Submit') ?>" class="button"><span><span><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Submit') ?></span></span></button>
        <span class="question-ajax-loading">&nbsp;</span>
    </div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var havequestionForm = new VarienForm('havequestionForm', true);

    // submit have a question by ajax
        jQuery('#havequestionForm').submit(function (e){
            e.preventDefault();
            jQuery(".question-ajax-loading").css('display','block');

            var name = jQuery("#name").val();
            var email = jQuery("#email").val();
            var comment = jQuery("#comment").val();
            var hideit = jQuery("#hideit").val();
            var prosku = jQuery("#prosku").val();
            var prostyle = jQuery("#prostyle").val();
            var procolor = jQuery("#procolor").val();
            var currentpage = jQuery("#currentpage").val();

            var dataString = 'name='+ name + '&email=' + email + '&comment=' + comment + '&hideit=' + hideit + '&prosku=' + prosku + '&prostyle=' + prostyle + '&procolor=' + procolor + '&currentpage=' + currentpage;

            url = jQuery('#havequestionForm').attr('action');

            jQuery.ajax( {
                url : url,
                Type : "POST",
                data: dataString, 
                success: function(data) {
                    jQuery(".question-ajax-msg").css('display','block');

                    if(data == 'SUCCESS'){
                        var successMsg = '<div class="success-msg">Your inquiry was submitted and will be responded to as soon as possible. Thank you for contacting us.</div>';
                        jQuery(".question-ajax-msg").html(successMsg);                      
                        jQuery("#comment").val('');
                    }                   
                    else {                      
                        jQuery(".question-ajax-msg").html(data);
                        jQuery("#comment").val('');
                    }

                    jQuery(".question-ajax-loading").css('display','none');
                    jQuery('.question-ajax-msg').delay(5000).fadeOut('slow');


                }

            });

            return false;
        });
//]]>
</script>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your time to share knowledge!

Answer (score 1):

You can create custom contact form,

Reference:
http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/magento-email/magento-custom-email-contact-form-with-notification-system/

Answer (score 1):

you can use below documentation

Custom Module with Custom Database Table

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/custom_module_with_custom_database_table

Front-End Editor Extension for Magento Commerce

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ALgdsMCVuH4

please see above the URL.

hope this will sure help you,